# R system2 syntax in linux

Tags: r, linux, system2

My problem is with system2 syntax.

I am trying to rename filenameA to filenameB in linux.
but I need to use full qualified paths, and rename does not like this, so I propose to use "mv".

I plan  use system2 and "mv" (eventually with map) to march across my list of original filenames and new filenames, but I am doing something wrong with system2 as the following code demonstrates:

- first I show you a single filename,
- then I use file.info() to show that file.info() can find the single file,
- then I show you the system2 "fail"
- then I show the recovered linux command issued by system2 succeeding in the shell.

Suggestions?

## here is a single filename

monthlyzipinfo[1]
[1] "/home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip"

## here is the result from file.info

> file.info(monthlyzipinfo[1])

```
                                                                        size isdir mode               mtime
```

/home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip 3911 FALSE  664 2017-05-17 09:38:18
                                                                                          ctime               atime  uid  gid
/home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip 2017-05-17 11:37:29 2017-05-17 09:27:48 1000 1000
                                                                            uname grname
/home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip   rob    rob

## but system2 fails

> system2(paste("ls -la", monthlyzipinfo[1]))
>   sh: 1: ls -la /home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip: not found

## but if I cut and paste the linux command from system2, that works;

rob@NewMachine:~$ ls -la /home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob 3911 May 17 09:38 /home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip
rob@NewMachine:~$

Comment: `?files` and then answer the Q: why not use the obvious R function on that page?

Comment: Because rename does not work with fully qualified pathnames.

Comment: or more specifically rename with substitutions.

Comment: This solves the single file case: " system2('mv', args=c(monthlyzipinfo[1], newnames[1]))" but purr doesn't play nicely. I'll repost as a purrr question.